Laravel 11 Middleware route group api doesnt work
I have a api project with Laravel 11, and i want to make a middleware for admin api.
AdminMiddleware.php (custom middleware)
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        if (!$user) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'forbidden',
                'message' => 'You need to log in first.'
            ], 403);
        }

        if ($user->authority !== 'admin') {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'forbidden',
                'message' => 'You are not an administrator.'
            ], 403);
        }

        return $next($request);

    }
}

bootstrap/app.php (new dir middleware config)
<?php

use App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        api: __DIR__.'/../routes/api.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->alias([
            "is_admin" => AdminMiddleware::class,
        ]);
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();


api.php (api route)
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\ProductController;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
})->middleware('auth:sanctum');


Route::prefix('/v1')->group(function () {
    Route::prefix('/admin')->group(function () {
        Route::prefix('/product')->group(function () {
            Route::get('/', [ProductController::class, "index"]);
            Route::post('/', [ProductController::class, "store"]);
            Route::get('/{id}', [ProductController::class, "show"]);
            Route::put('/{id}', [ProductController::class, "update"]);
            Route::delete('/{id}', [ProductController::class, "destroy"]);
        });
        Route::prefix('/user')->group(function () {
            Route::get('/', [UserController::class, "index"]);
            Route::get('/{id}', [UserController::class, "show"]);
            Route::post('/{id}', [UserController::class, "store"]);
            Route::put('/{id}', [UserController::class, "update"]);
            Route::delete('/{id}', [UserController::class, "destroy"]);
        });
    })->middleware("is_admin");

    Route::prefix('/auth')->group(function () {
        Route::post('/signup', [UserController::class, "signup"]);
        Route::post('/signin', [UserController::class, "signin"]);
        Route::post('/signout', [UserController::class, "signout"]);
    });
    Route::prefix('/product')->group(function () {
        Route::post('/', [ProductController::class, "product"]);
    });
});

I've just try using aliases and api method in config. but in api method case, all api route affected by the middleware. I'd try to use Route::group(['middleware' => 'is_admin'] and directly in api route by use the AdminMiddleware, and call in the method with middleware(AdminMiddleware::class). ya it's doesn't work.

Did you try to clear router: php artisan route:clear

what "doesn't work"? what are you expecting to happen and what is actually happening? any error? etc etc

@lagbox I use middleware so that only user with admin authority can access, but user with null authority can access it. (I've also tried dd($user) in middleware before next request but it's not showing.)

@TranVanHieu I just tried it, but it's still same.

does php artisan route:list show that middleware applied to those routes?

@FiezaGhifari, you want only the admin authority can access.right? But then which users have been assigned null in the authority column of users table??

@lagbox the middleware doesn't show in list :)

@Subha Yes, I have a user table with username, email, phone, authority, balance, and password columns. The username named "admin123" has authority "admin", and other user with username "user123" and authority are not set default (null). but if I login as a user123, I still can access the admin route (I've checked it correctly that in php artisan route:list is not showing...)

Okay but you mentioned in your first comment that that user with null authority can also access those route.And you want only the admin authority can access those routes.You have also mentioned that your middleware was correctly assigned to those routes.

@FiezaGhifari, I have posted my answer.Please check and let me know.

@Subha , I want to say thanks! my problem has been fixed.

@FiezaGhifari, I told you same to use middleware group in the comment section of my posted answer. BTW happy to help you and also upvoting your answer.Keep coding.

Okay, first of all I want to thank @subha for the solution provided and helped find some problems that are happening in my project. I ended up creating a new project and then moving some of the code to the new project... (I really have a skill issue lol)

solving the route problem.
Ive found this video on youtube ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=st7DtZA85fw )
this is the work code:

    route::group([
            "middleware" => ["auth:sanctum", "is_admin"]
        ], function(){
        Route::prefix('/admin')->group(function () {
            Route::prefix('/product')->group(function () {
                Route::get('/', [ProductController::class, "index"]);
                Route::post('/', [ProductController::class, "store"]);
                Route::get('/{id}', [ProductController::class, "show"]);
                Route::put('/{id}', [ProductController::class, "update"]);
                Route::delete('/{id}', [ProductController::class, "destroy"]);
            });
            Route::prefix('/user')->group(function () {
                Route::get('/', [UserController::class, "index"]);
                Route::get('/{id}', [UserController::class, "show"]);
                Route::post('/{id}', [UserController::class, "store"]);
                Route::put('/{id}', [UserController::class, "update"]);
                Route::delete('/{id}', [UserController::class, "destroy"]);
            });
        });
    });

if I use ->middleware("auth:sanctum"); its not work.
this dont work too:
Route::prefix('/admin')->group([
            "middleware" => ["auth:sanctum", "is_admin"]
        ], function(){....


solve the api auth problem (after signin. if user access other method, Auth::user() will return null).
(this one is a simple problem actually lol)
adding Accept: application/json on request header


Since you mentioned in your comment.

I use middleware so that only user with admin authority can access, but user with null authority can access it. (I've also tried dd($user) in middleware before next request but it's not showing.).

If you want only the admin authority can access those routes through AdminMiddleware,then you need to put another check for those users who have null authority.
Because in PHP null is a data-type which has no value.
If your AdminMiddleware assigned to the routes properly then below code will work.
Try this in AdminMiddleware.
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        if (!$user) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'forbidden',
                'message' => 'You need to log in first.'
            ], 403);
        }

        if ((is_null($user->authority) || $user->authority !== 'admin')) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'forbidden',
                'message' => 'You are not an administrator.'
            ], 403);
        }

    return $next($request);

}

Use the above code it will work.

I just tried it. but, not logged user still can access it. and I confirmed it again the index() method in the ProductController by adding dd(Auth::user()). and it displays null.
I've also tried dd($user) in middleware after $user = Auth::user() but it's not showing.

Have you properly set guards & providers  for Auth and how users are authenticated for each request?
There must be some issue with Auth  if it dd(Auth::user()) returns null. Go to the config/auth.php file and check it again.

Check also if the users properly loggedIn.

check if you have assigned Auth middleware to the routes.

I suddenly became a little dizzy. I just realized that even though I'm logged in even Auth::user() returns null. it's just that in the signin() method after Auth::attempt($input), Auth::user() can be used to generate a token. (I've tried for dd() and yes it works the data appears) it's just that when I try another route/method the Auth::user() data suddenly null :)

Got it. you meant that when you try (dd(Auth::user()) to another route/method it returns null. Because You didn't use Auth middleware to that route.So make it sure that you assign AdminMiddleware after your Auth middleware to the routes.

right this? ...->middleware(["auth", "is_admin"]);  I'm trying to do dd(Auth::user()); again in the index() method of the ProductController but still throws null.

As per the route-file you shared it should be auth:sanctum.And then run these both command php artisan route:clear & php artisan cache:clear.You should also try middlware group.

I've used php artisan route:clear but I can't do php artisan cache:clear SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'glaezz-in.cache' doesn't exist (Connection: mysql, SQL: delete from 'cache')
I've tried running it again as you directed (except cache:clear) and it still returns null. idk, I'm still new to Laravel 11 (but I don't seem to encounter any middleware problems in Laravel 10 (although I haven't used Route Group yet))

You are getting the error because by default laravel 11 is configured to use the database cache driver rather than file, which stores the serialized, cached objects in your application's database. In your case cache table is not created.I know this is getting complex and annoying that to solve one issue you encounter with multiple issue.But still if you want check the documents for cache-table
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/cache#configuration
